# Trying to use curl to create product but keep getting Error 500

Tags: shopify

I am trying to generate some test data for my Rails app that interfaces with Shopify through the shopify_api gem. I am using curl (command line utility) on a OS X machine. I keep getting Error 500 from Shopify (see below). I am at my wits end as I can't see what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
* About to connect() to [edited out].myshopify.com port 80 (#0)
*   Trying 204.93.213.44...
* connected
* Connected to [edited out].myshopify.com (204.93.213.44) port 80 (#0)
* Server auth using Basic with user '[edited out]'
> POST /admin/products.json HTTP/1.1
> Authorization: Basic [edited out]
> User-Agent: curl/7.24.0 (x86_64-apple-darwin12.0) libcurl/7.24.0 OpenSSL/0.9.8r zlib/1.2.5
> Host: [edited out].myshopify.com
> Accept: */*
> Content-Type: application/json
> Content-Length: 694
> 
* upload completely sent off: 694 out of 694 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
< Server: nginx
< Date: Sat, 22 Sep 2012 10:06:22 GMT
< Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Connection: keep-alive
< Status: 500 Internal Server Error
< X-Shopify-Shop-Api-Call-Limit: 1/500
< HTTP_X_SHOPIFY_SHOP_API_CALL_LIMIT: 1/500
< Cache-Control: no-cache
< X-Request-Id: 3a03a70617be67e89ab103a9b8053da9
< X-UA-Compatible: IE=Edge,chrome=1
< X-Runtime: 1.566916
< 
* Connection #0 to host [edited out].myshopify.com left intact
{"errors":"Error"}* Closing connection #0
```

This is how I invoke curl:

```
curl -v -X POST -d @ss12-absolute.json -H 'Content-Type: application/json' http://some_key:some_password@myshop.myshopify.com/admin/products.json
```

The POSTed data file looks like this:

```
{
  "product": {
    "title": "absolute",
    "handle": "ss12-absolute",
    "vendor": "deNada",
    "product_type": "top",
    "tags": "top,ss12,knits,casual,sleeveless",
    "body_html": "",
    "variants": [
      {
        "title": "absolute 08 eggplant",
        "sku": 555647,
        "price": "245.0",
        "compare_at_price": "245.0",
        "option1": "eggplant",
        "option2": "08",
        "option3": null
      }
    ],
    "options": [
      {
        "name": "Colour"
      },
      {
        "name": "Size"
      }
    ],
    "metafields": [
      {
        "namespace": "retail_pro",
        "key": "rp_style_sid",
        "value": -5642228920827310084,
        "value_type": "integer"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sku is a text field, you are submitting an integer. Switching that will fix it for you, we will fix it on our end so you can submit either.

Comment: Thank you so much for this. I knew that it was going to be something simple.

Answer (score 0):

The server is returning "**500 Internal Server Error**" so it's not an error in your client code, this needs to be debbugged in the server, if you don't have access to the server code that process your call (**myshop.myshopify.com/admin/products.json**) then you have to open an issue with the administrators or support team of that service so they have a look at what's wrong.

It's possible that a parameter in your **POST** data causes the error, but it's impossible to figure out exactly what's wrong without looking at the server code.

Comment: Yes, I understand that it's not me but the remote end. I posted here in the hope that someone from Shopify will be able to take a closer look at why this is happening.